# Running batch operations in MongoDB/ Robo3t

Tags: mongodb, robo3t

I have a list of users in a file and I want to update their record in a collection.

i.e

```
db.getCollection('users').update({username: "<a user>"}, { $set: { <set some values here> }})
```

How can I feed a list of users into this command or something similar in Robo 3T or from a terminal command line?

Comment: db.getCollection('users').update({username: "<a user>"}, { $set: {"key":"value","key2":"value2"}},{multi:true}} 
is something like this? using this you can update multi records with specific user

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following from the command line seems the easier options:

Option A) generate the update queries on the fly from the list of users and send to the mongo shell:

```
cat file.csv | awk '{ print("db.users.update({user:\""$1"\"},{ $set:{x:1} }) ")   }' | mongo
```

Option B) mongoimport

Step 1) Import the user list to the database in temporary collection:

```
 mongoimport --type csv -d test -c usersToUpdate --headerline  file.csv
```

file.csv:

```
 userlist
 John
 Donald
 Jeny
```

Step 2) As soon as the collection is imported you can do as follow:

```
  db.usersToUpdate.find({},{_id:0,userlist:1}).forEach(function(theuser){      db.users.update({username: theuser.userlist}, { $set: { <set some values here> }}); print(theuser+" record updated successfully");      })
```

Step 3) Finally you can clean the temporary usersToUpdate collection with:

```
  db.usersToUpdate.drop()
```